# tensorflow_model server does not work in colab

Tags: tensorflow, server, model

while running the tutorial [here](http://cognitiveai.org/2020/09/08/using-tensorflow-ranking-bert-tfr-bert-an-end-to-end-example/), I run

```
tensorflow_model_server \
  --rest_api_port=8501 \
  --model_name=tfrbert \
  --model_base_path="/content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/"
```

in colab, but its running takes a long time, and the output is:

```
2021-08-06 14:08:56.175079: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:89] Building single TensorFlow model file config:  model_name: tfrbert model_base_path: /content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/
2021-08-06 14:08:56.175256: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:465] Adding/updating models.
2021-08-06 14:08:56.175287: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:591]  (Re-)adding model: tfrbert
2021-08-06 14:08:56.282059: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:740] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: tfrbert version: 1628175000}
2021-08-06 14:08:56.282118: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: tfrbert version: 1628175000}
2021-08-06 14:08:56.282136: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: tfrbert version: 1628175000}
2021-08-06 14:08:56.282741: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:38] Reading SavedModel from: /content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/1628175000
2021-08-06 14:08:56.307745: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:90] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-08-06 14:08:56.307841: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:132] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: /content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/1628175000
2021-08-06 14:08:56.308630: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-08-06 14:08:56.511612: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:206] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2021-08-06 14:08:56.539804: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:114] CPU Frequency: 2299995000 Hz
2021-08-06 14:08:57.499446: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:190] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: /content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/1628175000
2021-08-06 14:08:57.567048: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:277] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 1284304 microseconds.
2021-08-06 14:08:57.577930: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup_util.cc:59] No warmup data file found at /content/drive/MyDrive/app/model1/export/latest_model/1628175000/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2021-08-06 14:08:57.582683: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded servable version {name: tfrbert version: 1628175000}
2021-08-06 14:08:57.583905: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:486] Finished adding/updating models
2021-08-06 14:08:57.583970: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:367] Profiler service is enabled
2021-08-06 14:08:57.584549: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:393] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
[evhttp_server.cc : 245] NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ...
2021-08-06 14:08:57.585146: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:414] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
```

what is the problem??

Comment: Colab generally has no port forwarding and therefore cannot serve models.

Comment: @StanleyZheng I did it, as you can do on your local machine. After running the model_server you can send request to localhost:8501

Answer (score 1):

I saw the link of tutorial you have provided. It has considered running the `tensorflow_model_server` as a bash shell script. However you can run it in Google Colab, but you may decorate this command with some tools to get behaviour like other python regular codes.

`tensorflow_model_server` runs a web server service, and it will not going to end immediately, since it is waiting to get requests and give you response. If you want to make it to run in background and give you back the UI in order to run other cells, modify the code like this:

```sh
%%bash --bg 
nohup tensorflow_model_server \
  --rest_api_port=8501\
  --model_name=tfrbert\
  --model_base_path="path/to/dir" > server.log 2>&1
```

Description of changes:

- `%%bash --bg`: is a jupyter magic command, which tells Colab it is a bash script, aims to running in background
- `nohup`: abbreviation of "no hang up", which let's run command immune to hang up.
- `> server.log 2&1`: Saves the command output in `server.log` file instead of printing them to stdout. (The output you have added in your question will no longer be visible in UI, but they will be printed in a file)

Comment: Thanks. I do that and it says: Starting job # 1 in a separate thread. but while doing the last part of http://cognitiveai.org/2020/09/08/using-tensorflow-ranking-bert-tfr-bert-an-end-to-end-example/ that means from client part, I encountered with this error:  (in the next comment)

Comment: grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
 status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
 details = "input tensor alias not found in signature: input_ranking_data. Inputs expected to be in the set {inputs}."
 debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1628345826.159512315","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:0.0.0.0:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"input tensor alias not found in signature: input_ranking_data. Inputs expected to be in the set {inputs}.","grpc_status":3}"

Comment: @ShimaGhasemi : So, the model_server is running properly. And the above printed message is the response of model_server. And this error comes from the part of your code which makes the json file to request. I think you should replace `'input_ranking_data'` with `'inputs'` in this line: https://github.com/cognitiveailab/ranking/blob/master/tensorflow_ranking/extension/examples/tfrbert_client_predict_from_json.py#L136

Comment: thanks a lot. now running the last part of cognitiveai.org/2020/09/08/… that means from client part, i recieved  deadline exceeded error. like this: grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
 status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
 details = "Deadline Exceeded"
 debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1628780023.957204015","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:0.0.0.0:8500","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1062,"grpc_message":"Deadline Exceeded","grpc_status":4}"
>